# Problemas al pasar props con TypeScript con React entre dos componentes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en React con TypeScript y tengo la siguiente duda. Lo veremos mejor con el código. Aquí el código de mi componente App:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddCategory from "./components/AddCategory";

function App() {
  const [information, setInformation] = useState<string[]>([
    "Ronaldo",
    "Zidane",
    "Roberto Carlos",
    "Morientes",
  ]);
    
  // let handleSubmit = (e: string) => {
  //   setCategories(...categories, e)
  // };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Gif Expert App</h1>

        <AddCategory setInformation={setInformation}/>
        <hr />

        <ol>
          {information.map((information) => {
            return <li key={information}>{information}</li>;
          })}
        </ol>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Y aquí el código de mi componente hijo: AddCategory.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

function AddCategory() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("How I met your mother");

  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //It avoids the page to load again when the form is submitted
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="textBar"
        value={inputValue}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

export default AddCategory;
```

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es que cuando escribo en la barra de texto de `AddCategory` y envío la información (con el `handleSubmit`, ya sé que me falta por escribir el código que haría eso, pero básicamente sería usar el `setInformation` del padre), me setee la información en el `useState` de `App`.
El problema es que para hacer eso, primero tendré que pasar como parámetro el `setInformation` del padre al hijo. Al estar haciéndolo con TypeScript, no sé exactamente cómo enviarlo. Si lo envío así   `<AddCategory setInformation={setInformation}/>` me da el siguiente error: `Type '{ setInformation: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`; si lo pongo así  `<AddCategory setInformation={setInformation:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>}/>` me da el siguiente error `Type '{ setInformation: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` (que es el mismo error que me daba de la otra forma vaya) y, en resumen, que no soy capaz de pasarle esa propiedad al hijo porque me da error constantemente. ¿Alguien sabe cómo podría indicárselo con TypeScript para que funcione? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya he descubierto la forma de hacerlo. A ver, me tengo que crear una interfaz.

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export interface SetInformationProps {
  setInformation: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>;
}
```

El tipo de `setInformation` te lo marca Visual Studio Code si te sitúas sobre `setInformation`, te hace un hover. Ahora en mi componente padre le pasaría la prop de la siguiente forma:

```
<AddCategory setInformation={setInformation} />
```

Y en el componente hijo tengo que importar la interfaz `import { InformationProps } from "../interfaces";` y una vez que la tengo importada en el método que quiero modificar el `useState` del padre hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //It avoids the page to load again when the form is submitted
    setInformation((information: string[]) => [...information, inputValue]);
  };
```

Aquí es importante que accedo a information gracias al método `setter` del `useState`, porque realmente `information` no lo paso en mi interfaz, por eso lo hago así. Desestructuro el array y le meto mi valor al final del array. Y, se me olvidaba,

```
function AddCategory({ setInformation }: InformationProps)
```

He de pasar a esta función el `setter` del padre con su interfaz, para que no me de error.

P.D. La interfaz se puede hacer de forma más limpia de esta forma:

```
export interface SetInformationProps {
  setInformation: (information: string[]) => void;
}
```

Simplemente nos aprovechamos de las propiedades del `useState` para definir la interfaz. A fin de cuentas, ¿qué hace el `setInformation`? Actúa sobre un array de strings (`information[]`) y no retorna nada, por lo tanto su valor de retorno es `void`.